# Swift Stack View from Apple's Food Tracker app tutorial displaying both horizontal and vertical buttons

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on Apple's Food Tracker tutorial in Swift 3.2 and cannot get the ratings' backgrounds to display properly. Everything is fine to this point; no warnings or errors. The ratings' backgrounds (red squares) are embedded in a horizontal view stack. Five red squares display horizontally, which is correct, but four red squares display vertically also, which is incorrect. I've triple checked the code and all looks okay. I've also searched Stack Overflow but found nothing that helped. I've included the code for the RatingControl.swift file for reference. (I am unable to post an image b/c I don't have sufficient reputation points.) Is the problem possibly related to constraints? Any help would be appreciated. [ratings buttons][1]

```
//
//  RatingControl.swift
//  FoodTracker
//
//  Created by Jane Appleseed on 10/17/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Apple Inc. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

@IBDesignable class ratingControl: UIStackView {

//MARK: Properties
private var ratingButtons = [UIButton]()

var rating = 0

//MARK: Initialization
override init(frame: CGRect) {
super.init(frame: frame)
setupButtons()
}

required init(coder: NSCoder){
super.init(coder: coder)
setupButtons()
}

//MARK: Button Action
func ratingButtonTapped(button: UIButton) {
print("Button pressed ")
}

//MARK: Private Methods
private func setupButtons() {
for _ in 0..<5 {
// Create the button
let button = UIButton()
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

// Add constraints
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true
button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true

// Setup the button action
button.addTarget(self, action:                                                                               #selector(ratingControl.ratingButtonTapped(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)

// Add the button to the stack
addArrangedSubview(button)

// Add the new button to the rating button array
ratingButtons.append(button)
}
}
}


//![ratings buttons][1]


//[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofa78.jpg
```

Comment: What's the class set it for your vertical stackview in IB?

Comment: Dan, thanks for getting back. If I understand your question, I set the vertical stackview in IB per the tutorial. The vertical stackview also includes the horizontal stackview embedded in it. Code was running fine until the horizontal stackview.

Comment: The tutorial would have told you to set the class of the horizontal stack view to in IB to your `ratingControl`.  Based on what your view looks like, it seems that you also set the class of your vertical stack view to `ratingControl`, which you don't want.

Comment: I already fixed the problem -- switched the stack views and reset  constraints. But now I have a problem in the ViewController.swift file that I didn't have before: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value." It was working at first, but is now broken. Will have to do more troubleshooting. Thanks.